# Whats the best way to trigger stoppage of a streaming context once the receiver is done fetching all the records

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have implemented a custom receiver to fetch data from Elastic Search in batches of x records continuously. Once, the receiver is done fetching all the records from Elastic Search for a particular query, I want to stop the streaming context. What's the best approach to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide, Max Time to successfully fetch all x records and then apply `ssc.awaitTermination(Max time);` function or you can manually stop your streaming context using `ssc.stop();`